# Align division at the bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way I can align a division at the bottom of the actual HTML page, and not that of the screen, so if the page height is larger than that of the screen, meaning there is a scroll, the division should stay fixed at the bottom.

```
.contact_us{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

With this set up in the css, it seems like it uses the bottom of the screen and not page it's self

Comment: Do your parent div have postion: relative?

Comment: could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Seems to come right if the parent has a relative position, but why is that @user874774 ?

Comment: @HoseaKambonde because absolute refers to the first parent with non static (default) positioning. By default, the viewport (window) is the only element which is kinda considered as non default. relative positioning is very handy because it has no effect if you don't set offsets (top, left ...) beside changing the type of positioning.

Comment: It will use the closest parent with a position of relative as a "reference".

Comment: @user874774 make it an answer or I will :)

Comment: @user874774 not necessarely `relative`, just the first non-static. Which include relative and absolute.

Comment: @TecHunter I had to take a break. Good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, you need to have somewhere to refer to when using css positioning or it will automatically refer to Window.
`absolute` refers to the first parent with non static (default) positioning.
The most common trick is to use relative positioning which is very handy because it has no effect if you don't set offsets (top, left ...) beside changing the type of positioning thus becoming the reference for all positioning for its children

You can see some effects here :

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/M4kSQ/

**Shorthand answer**

make one parent with non-static position like

```
#some_parent{
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Footer always at bottom of page (even if content is short)

**DEMO:** http://gvee.co.uk/files/html/footer.htm

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="body">body</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#container
{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#header
{
    background: #ff0;
    padding: 10px;
}

#body
{
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

#footer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background: #6cf;
}
```

### Conditional IE CSS

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```